# Swift Networking using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am trying to make network requests to download data and put it into a `UITableView`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but when I call `viewModel.request()` in the ViewController it is not populating the `UITableView`.

I left some of the code out to make it simple but the `UITableView` works fine when using `URLSession`, I just can't get it to work with **`Combine`**.

If I print `viewModel.sections` in `viewDidLoad()`, it prints an empty array:

ViewController

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //TableView Setup
        setUpTableView()
        
        viewModel.request()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return viewModel.sections.count
     }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.sections[section].sports.count
    }

}
```

TestViewModel

```swift
class TestViewModel {
    
    @Published var sections: [Sections] = []
    var date: Date = Date()
    var cancellables: AnyCancellable?

    func request(){

        let nfl = NetworkManager.download(endpoint: .nfl, date: date.query())
        .decode(type: EventModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        
        let nba = NetworkManager.download(endpoint: .nba, date: date.query())
        .decode(type: EventModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        
        let mlb = NetworkManager.download(endpoint: .mlb, date: date.query())
        .decode(type: EventModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        
        let nhl = NetworkManager.download(endpoint: .nhl, date: date.query())
        .decode(type: EventModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        
        self.cancellables = Publishers.Zip4(nfl, nba, mlb, nhl)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error:",error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (nfl, nba, mlb, nhl) in
      
            var section: [Sections] = []

            if !nfl.events.isEmpty {
                section.append(.init(icon: "football.fill", title: "NFL", sports: nfl.events, leagues: nfl.leagues))
            }
            if !nba.events.isEmpty {
                section.append(.init(icon: "basketball.fill", title: "NBA", sports: nba.events, leagues: nba.leagues))
            }
            if !mlb.events.isEmpty {
                section.append(.init(icon: "baseball.fill", title: "MLB", sports: mlb.events, leagues: mlb.leagues))
            }
            if !nhl.events.isEmpty {
                section.append(.init(icon: "hockey.puck.fill", title: "NHL", sports: nhl.events, leagues: nhl.leagues))
            }
            
            self?.sections = section
            
        })
        // This is Empty
        print(self.sections)
    }
}
```

NetworkManager

```swift
class NetworkManager {
    
    static func download(endpoint: Endpoint, date: String) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "***API URL***")!
        let final = url.appendingPathComponent(endpoint.build())
        
        var components = URLComponents(url: final, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "dates", value: date),
        ]
        let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        return
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            .tryMap{(data, response) -> Data in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
                return data
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this with `URLSession`? You would need to reload the table view in the completion handler, right? I don't see you reloading your table view anywhere... And of course `print(self.sections)` is going to print an empty array, because just like `URLSession`, Combine is asynchronous too.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using SwiftUI @Published method in UIKit. What works best is CurrentValueSubject for UIKit.

Change you sections to be `var sections CurrentValueSubject<[Sections], Never>([])` in your VM. Then in your VM request function, build up the sections data (_values) and send by `sections.send(_values)`

In your controller you need to bind to the VM.sections by `viewModel.sections.sink { in $0 }` where $0 is your data.